# Content Moves when resizing

Tags: html, css

I've started making a website, and would like a banner to sit under my nav bar.
I originally had both divs positioned exactly how i wanted them, however upon resizing, the right div moved under the left div.
Both were positioned using float:left and float:right.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Welcome </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style1.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<div id="topHeader">
<div id="logo">
<img src="Images/HeaderLogo.png"  alt="Logo for Matt Meadows">
</div>

</div> <!--End of topHeader -->
</div> <!--End of Header -->
<nav>
<div id="nav-links">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Portfolio</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>

</nav>
<div id="contentHeaderContainer">
<div id="contentHeader">
<img src="Images/HomePageContentHeader.png">
<div id="headerText">
<h1 id="welcome">WELCOME</h1>
<p class="Text1">The Way Website Development should be...</p>
<p class="Text2">UNIQUE</p>
<p class="Text5">CONCISE</p>
<p class="Text3">VIBRANT</p>
<p class="Text4">PROFESSIONAL</p>
<p class="Text6">SIMPLE</p>
</div> <!--End of headerText -->
</div> <!--End of contentHeader -->
</div> <!--End of contentHeaderContainer -->
</div> <!--End of wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html
{
margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#wrapper
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#topHeader
{
width: 100%;
height:75px;
background: rgb(36,36,36); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(36,36,36,1) 0%, rgba(52,52,52,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(36,36,36,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(52,52,52,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(36,36,36,1) 0%,rgba(52,52,52,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(36,36,36,1) 0%,rgba(52,52,52,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(36,36,36,1) 0%,rgba(52,52,52,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(36,36,36,1) 0%,rgba(52,52,52,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#242424', endColorstr='#343434',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

#logo
{
margin-left: 50px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

nav
{
float:left;
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
background: url('Images/NavBG.png');
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 15px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 7px 15px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
box-shadow:         0px 7px 15px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
}

#nav-links
{
margin: 0 auto;
}

ul
{
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
width: 700px;
}

li
{
display:inline;
float:left;
padding: 10px 55px 10px 55px;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #CCCCCC;
-webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: background 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: background 0.5s ease;
transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

li:hover
{
background: #4d4c4c;
color: #FFF;
}

#contentHeaderContainer
{
height: 450px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background: rgb(36,36,36); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(36,36,36,1) 0%, rgba(52,52,52,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(36,36,36,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(52,52,52,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(36,36,36,1) 0%,rgba(52,52,52,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(36,36,36,1) 0%,rgba(52,52,52,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(36,36,36,1) 0%,rgba(52,52,52,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(36,36,36,1) 0%,rgba(52,52,52,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#242424', endColorstr='#343434',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 15px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 7px 15px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
box-shadow:         0px 7px 15px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
}


#contentHeader img
{
float:left;
margin-top: 50px;
}


#headerText
{
float:right;
width: 700px;
height: 300px;
}

#welcome
{
font-family: "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #cccccc
}

p
{
font-family: "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.Text1
{
color: #999999;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.Text2
{
color:#8d9999;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

.Text3
{
color:#8d9999;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 350px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

.Text4
{
color:#8d9999;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

.Text5
{
float:right;
color:#8d9999;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top:-50px;
}

.Text6
{
float:right;
color:#8d9999;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top:-50px;
}
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/w6qxU/

I would like both child divs within #contentHeaderContainer to remain completely still, even when resizing. E.G when resizing the window, the border of the window moves, yet the content remains absolutely still.

Comment: You have quite a few `<div>`s there.  Can you be more specific about which ones are not acting how you want?

Comment: Yeah I am not real sure exactly what you are asking, if you put position: absolute; in the #wrapper id, will that accomplish what you are trying to do?

Comment: based on your fiddle - try this:`#headerText {
    position:fixed;
    top:160px;
    left:50px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
}`  and set the top and left to where you like

Comment: Have edited post to reflect more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the image and `headerText` stay side by side, you must give them enough room to do so. Add an appropriate width to the `#wrapper`

```
#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:960px;
}
```

[JSFiddle (wrapper/width)](http://jsfiddle.net/tvPcU/1/)

If you always want to occupy the whole width, use `min-width` instead

```
#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-width:960px;
}
```

[JSFiddle (wrapper/min-width)](http://jsfiddle.net/tvPcU/2/)

Comment: Would this still work even though i'd like the website to remain full screen of the browser?

Comment: @MattMeadows I don't understand this. If it stays full screen, it doesn't resize.

Comment: The wrapper holds the nav and header correctly, however, the #headerText moves down under #contentHeader img when resizing

Comment: @MattMeadows Yes, but what do you mean with "the website to remain full screen"?

Comment: Apologies.
The design I have, utilises all of the browser space available, E.G header uses 100% width, nav, content etc, if I change the body,html to a width of 960px instead of 100%, it sets at only 960px wide, not utilising all of the space available.

Answer (score 4):

Are asking about the `#contentHeader img` and `#headerText`? - these are the ones that **change position on window resize** for me.

You could position them absolutely and give them `left:0;` and `right:0;` instead of `float:left;` and `float:right;` respectively.

Maybe, something like that:

```
#contentHeader {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

#contentHeader img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:90px;
}

#headerText {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:45px;
    width:700px;
    height:300px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6qxU/1/)

This way the image won't push the text down, but will stay behind it. If this is not what you want you might need to clarify the question a little.

**EDIT:**

To make the element stay at a fixed distance between each other you will have to assign a fixed width to the container. But normally they will then not stay centered when you resize the window, as the left edge will start pushing the container to the right. But you can use a trick and keep the equally far form the center of the page on window resize by doing something like this (for example we asume a fixed width of 1200px):

```
#contentHeader {
    position:relative;
    width:1px;
}

#contentHeaderImg {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width:500px;
    top:90px;
    text-align:left;
}

#headerText {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:45px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Now you just need to adjust the widths of the left and right positioned elements so that they sit where you want them to sit =)

[Here it's on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/w6qxU/2/) I made another div around the image (`#contentHeaderImg`) here, cause I don't know your image width -  for easier positioning.

> **So, assigned the width should do the trick, but you can not have
>   floating to the edge and the same arrangement of the two elements at
>   the same time while resizing ... that would be possible only if you
>   proportionally scale all the header contents.**

Comment: I would like both div's to remain completely still when resizing, as in, the browser window overlaps when made smaller, yet the content still remains as it was.

Comment: You would need to decide at what distance you want to keep the two elements (assigne a fixed width). I will update the answer and you can tell me if it is more in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the content from moving when resizing the browser window, just you need to avoid using the absolute measurement unit (pixel) and use only the percentage % and the viewport unit vw. This worked perfectly with me.I have used these styles for my Divs.

```
.centercolumn {
float: left;
width: 50%;
padding: 1%;
background-color: #f8df67;
height: 80vh;
margin-top: 1%;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 1%;}


.sidecolumn {
float: left;
width: 20%;
padding: 1%;
margin-top: 1%;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-bottom: 1%;
height: 80vh;}
```